# How to match Object field with String in in Django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, postgresql-9.4

Initially, when I am saving this 'status' field in database it is (=models.CharField(max_length=200))

So, Now When I am trying to get this data in HTML template and trying to match with "string" likes the following code.

But it does not working.It always shows the   {% else %} output.

```html
    <td>
            {% if order.status == "inprogress" %}
              <span class="label label-warning">inprogress</span>
            {% elif order.status == "issued" %}
              <span class="label label-warning">issued</span>
            {% elif order.status == "completed" %}
             <span class="label label-warning">completed</span>
            {% else %}
              <span class="label label-warning">overdue</span>
            {% endif %}

          </td>
```

Comment: Have you printed `order.status` to see its output? Perhaps order.status is does not contain the value you expect: capitalization, maybe it's an FK, and so on.

Comment: yes, it is FK .
could you give a solution for that.
Thanks

Comment: Show your relevant `models.py`, please...

Comment: Please, check question details. I already updated it.

Comment: @pskpartha instead of `if order.status ==` try `if order.status.portStatus ==`

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working. BTW I am too novice in django.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ or update your question with solutions. Instead consider posting an answer which you can mark as accepted. This will tell others that the question has been solved. Thank you. For reference you can see what I've rolled back in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45175197/revisions).

Comment: I am not getting option 'accepted' ! Thanks

Comment: @pskpartha, BTW: If you want a specific person to be notified of your comment, you need to include their ID in your comment with an `@` in front of it. For instance, for me it would be `@Makyen`. If you do this as the first thing in your comment, the system will provide auto-complete suggestions from those who have already posted comments on that answer/question. The original poster of the answer/question on which you are commenting will always be notified. This [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/271271) has more information.

Comment: @pskpartha, For you to be able to accept an answer there needs to be an answer. If it's your own answer, then the system sometimes makes you wait 24/48 hours prior to accepting it. When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). However, if you solved it based on someone's comment you should let them know with `@[user name]` and give them a chance to Answer. If they don't (give them at least 24 hours, they may have commented just before heading to bed, you never know) then please do add an answer of your own.